# How to merge a select statement with a new dynamic values as columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

In my sql server code, I have this select statement

```
select distinct 
    a.HireLastName, 
    a.HireFirstName, 
    a.HireID, 
    a.Position_ID, 
    a.BarNumber, 
    a.Archived, 
    a.DateArchived, 
    b.Position_Name
from NewHire a 
join Position b on a.Position_ID = b.Position_ID
join WorkPeriod c on a.hireID = c.HireID
where a.Archived = 0 and c.InquiryID is not null 
order by a.HireID DESC, a.HireLastName, a.HireFirstName
```

And I want to add a new column to it. However this column is not a column from a table, its just used to store a `float` from a calculation I make from existing columns.

The number I get is calculated like this:
`@acc` is the `a.HireID` from the above select statement.

```
CAST((select COUNT(*) from Hire_Response WHERE HireID = @acc AND (HireResponse = 0 OR HireResponse = 1)) as FLOAT) / 
CAST((select COUNT(*) from Hire_Response WHERE HireID = @acc) as FLOAT)
```

How can I do this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
select distinct 
    a.HireLastName, 
    a.HireFirstName, 
    a.HireID, 
    a.Position_ID, 
    a.BarNumber, 
    a.Archived, 
    a.DateArchived, 
    b.Position_Name,
    CAST((select COUNT(*) from Hire_Response WHERE HireID = a.HireID AND 
       (HireResponse = 0 OR HireResponse = 1)) as FLOAT) / 
     CAST((select case when COUNT(*) = 0 then 1 else COUNT(*) end from Hire_Response WHERE HireID = a.HireID) as FLOAT) as mySpecialColumn
from NewHire a 
join Position b on a.Position_ID = b.Position_ID
join WorkPeriod c on a.hireID = c.HireID
where a.Archived = 0 and c.InquiryID is not null 
order by a.HireID DESC, a.HireLastName, a.HireFirstName
```

Comment: If there is a divide by zero, it needs to default to 0.

Comment: @omega I updated my answer per your comment.  It should sidestep the divide by zero errors.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the calculation to your select statement as I've put below, I also alaised the calculation with a Column name for you:

```
select distinct 
    a.HireLastName, 
    a.HireFirstName, 
    a.HireID, 
    a.Position_ID, 
    a.BarNumber, 
    a.Archived, 
    a.DateArchived, 
    b.Position_Name,
    CAST((select COUNT(*) from Hire_Response WHERE HireID = a.HierID AND 
         (HireResponse = 0 OR HireResponse = 1)) as FLOAT) / 
    CAST((select COUNT(*) from Hire_Response WHERE HireID = a.HierID) as FLOAT) AS [Calculation]
from NewHire a 
join Position b on a.Position_ID = b.Position_ID
join WorkPeriod c on a.hireID = c.HireID
where a.Archived = 0 and c.InquiryID is not null 
order by a.HireID DESC, a.HireLastName, a.HireFirstName
```

Comment: If there is a divide by zero, it needs to default to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an alias for the column.
This is assuming that your calculation is correct reference the column you need.

```
select
    (Calculated Column expression) as CalculatedColumn,
    *
from
    TableName


select distinct 
    a.HireLastName, 
    a.HireFirstName, 
    a.HireID, 
    a.Position_ID, 
    a.BarNumber, 
    a.Archived, 
    a.DateArchived, 
    b.Position_Name,
    (CAST((select COUNT(*) from Hire_Response WHERE HireID = a.HireIDAND (HireResponse = 0 OR  HireResponse = 1)) as FLOAT) / 
    CAST((select COUNT(*) from Hire_Response WHERE HireID = a.HireID) as FLOAT)) as CalculatedColumn
from NewHire a 
join Position b on a.Position_ID = b.Position_ID
join WorkPeriod c on a.hireID = c.HireID
where a.Archived = 0 and c.InquiryID is not null 
order by a.HireID DESC, a.HireLastName, a.HireFirstName
```

Answer (score 0):

Tough trying to figure out the goal without an example of the data structure but here goes.  I added a new JOIN, and the GROUP BY clause:

```
select distinct 
    a.HireLastName, 
    a.HireFirstName, 
    a.HireID, 
    a.Position_ID, 
    a.BarNumber, 
    a.Archived, 
    a.DateArchived, 
    b.Position_Name,
    sum(case when hr.HireResponse in (0, 1) then 1.00 else 0.00 end) as Numerator,
    count(hr.*) as Denominator,
    sum(case when hr.HireResponse in (0, 1) then 1.00 else 0.00 end) / count(hr.*) as Fraction

from 
    NewHire a  join 
    Position b on a.Position_ID = b.Position_ID  join 
    WorkPeriod c on a.hireID = c.HireID  inner join
    Hire_Response hr on a.HireID = hr.HireID

where 
    a.Archived = 0 
    and c.InquiryID is not null 

group by
    a.HireLastName, 
    a.HireFirstName, 
    a.HireID, 
    a.Position_ID, 
    a.BarNumber, 
    a.Archived, 
    a.DateArchived, 
    b.Position_Name

order by 
    a.HireID DESC, a.HireLastName, a.HireFirstName
```